# spring controller scope and storing session data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am a newbie to spring scope .

I have a code like follows

```
   @Controller
   public class PageController extends AbstractController {

private ABCManager abcManager;// repository singleton bean.

@Inject
public PageController(final ABCManager accountDiaryManager){
    this.abcManager= abcManager;
}

    @RequestMapping(value="/createpage",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Page createPage(@RequestParam(value="viewtype")final String viewtype, final WebRequest request)
    {
    final ABC abc= (abc) request.getAttribute(AbstractController.CURRENT_ABC, WebRequest.SCOPE_SESSION);

        .........
       abcManager.createPage(Long.valueOf(abc.getId()), page);
request.setAttribute("abc", abcManager.getabc(abc.getId()),WebRequest.SCOPE_SESSION);
 }
```

Since abc object can change many times within the same user session as abc is the root object and contains tree structure and user action will involve change anywhere in the sub object. So when an edit is performed i save the modified abc object inside the request so the latest abc object is avaiable everytime inside the request. this abc can grow very very big and that is my concern. Is it a good way to do like this?

I would like to know if this is a good practice to code like this. Is this a thread safe way? What is the best alterative avaiable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get/Put to session object is not thread safe. In your case, since you are storing data related to particular user in session, it is safe to do so as long as you don't expect same user to perform multiple actions which can update the session at the same time.  Having said that, if you are really developing a production ready system and in which case you will end up with multiple application servers, you need to think about what will be your strategy for session management -  you can use sticky session at webserver (Apache httpd for example) so that all request belonging to same session is forwarded to same app server, or you need to enable session replication among app servers.
2. ABC growing very big need to be quantified.  If you assume that it grows to 1MB in size, and if you have allocated 2 GB RAM to your app server's JVM, and assuming 1 GB of it is free for application's memory requirements, then, you can store data of upto 1000 users.  Based on how many concurrent sessions that you plan to support, you will have to configure right amount of RAM.
3. If ABC stores transient data, like shopping cart information and which you are okay to lose during server restarts, then your approach is alright.  If you do not want to lose the data, then, you can consider using cache systems, or key-value type of NoSQL stores (CouchBase, Redis, etc).  RDBMS is also an option but it really depends on nature of data that you are trying to maintain in session and whether they really have session semantics or you are just storing them in session for convenience.